# How to order in Laravel high to low , low to high products - by price with this code?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

How to order in Laravel high to low , low to high products - by price with this code? I got it all for a default presentation but i want to add 2 links to make quesy string so only when i click them the products will be ordered like high to low or low to high - other wise when it is not clicked on any links its ordered by default - DESC OR ASC
This is the code by order: MODEL CONTROLLER HTML:

```
static public function getProducts($url_category, &$data) {

    $data['products'] = [];

    if ($category = Categorie::where('url', '=', $url_category)->first()) {

        $category = $category->toArray();
        $data['title'] = $data['title'] . $category['title'];
        $data['url_category'] = $url_category;

        if ($products = Categorie::find($category['id'])->products) {

            $data['products'] = $products->toArray();
        }
    }
}





function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->middleware('adminAuth');
}

public function index() {
    self::$data['products'] = Product::all()->toArray();
    return view('cms.products', self::$data);
}

public function create() {
    self::$data['categories'] = Categorie::all()->toArray();
    return view('cms.add_product', self::$data);
}

public function store(ProductRequest $request) {
    Product::save_new($request);
    return redirect('cms/products');
}

public function show($id) {
    self::$data['product_id'] = $id;
    return view('cms.delete_product', self::$data);
}

public function edit($id) {
    self::$data['categories'] = Categorie::all()->toArray();
    self::$data['product'] = Product::find($id)->toArray();
    return view('cms.edit_product', self::$data);
}

public function update(ProductRequest $request, $id) {
    Product::update_product($request, $id);
    return redirect('cms/products');
}

public function destroy($id) {
    Product::destroy($id);
    Session::flash('sm', $request['title'] . ' has been deleted');
    return redirect('cms/products');
}





@if($products)

<a href='{{url('shop/' . $url_category . '?order=high')}}' class='btn btn-link'>From High to Low</a>|
<a href='{{url('shop/' . $url_category . '?order=low')}}' class='btn btn-link' style='color:purple;'>From Low to High</a>

<div class="row">
    @foreach($products as $row)
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
        <h3>{{ $row['title'] }}</h3>
        <p><a href="{{url('shop/'. $url_category . '/' . $row['url'])}}"><img alt="{{ $row['title'] }}" border="0" width="200" height="200" src="{{ asset('images/' . $row['image']) }}"></a></p>
        <p>{!! $row['article'] !!}</p>
        <p><strong>Price on site: </strong>{{ $row['price'] }}$</p>
        <p>
            <a href="{{url('shop/'. $url_category . '/' . $row['url'])}}" class="btn btn-warning">View Product Details</a>
            <input @if( Cart::get($row['id'] )) disabled="disabled" @endif data-id="{{ $row['id'] }}" type="button" class="add-to-cart-btn btn btn-success" value="+ Add To Cart"/>
        </p>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
@else 
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <p><ans>No Products For This Category...</ans></p>
    </div>
</div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **usort()** function in your controller:

```
$data['products'] = $products->toArray();
if (request()->has('order') {
    usort($data['products'], function($a, $b) {
        return (request('order') == 'high') ? $b['price'] - 
$a['price'] : $a['price'] - $b['price'];
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider to not cast `$products` to an array, but keep it as a collection instead. That way you can use Laravel's `sortBy()` method to sort the collection in a legible way.

```
// $order can be 'asc' or 'desc', which you determine in your controller
@foreach ($products->sortBy('column', $order) as $row)
```

See documentation here: [Collections / sortBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections#method-sortby)